how to decrypt stream based zipcrypto with password?
This is my test of Zipcrypto decryption with known password, It's my own exercise on what i have learned so far , but the code produces bytes different from expected plaintext and i can't figure out why.
Here is my code:
#define CRC_UPDATE_BYTE(crc, byte) (CRC_TABLE[((crc) ^ (byte)) & 0xFF] ^ ((crc) >> 8))
#define UPDATE_KEYS(b) \
    do { \
        key0 = CRC_UPDATE_BYTE(key0, b); \
        key1 = (key1 + (key0 & 0xFF)) * 0x8088405 + 1; \
        key2 = CRC_UPDATE_BYTE(key2, (uint8_t)(key1 >> 24)); \
    } while(0)

#define DECRYPT_BYTE_1 uint32_t temp = key2 | 2;
#define DECRYPT_BYTE_2 ((uint8_t)((temp * (temp ^ 1)) >> 8))

uint32_t KeyMem0, KeyMem1, KeyMem2,Key0,Key1,Key2;
crcword CRC_TABLE[256], crcinvtab[256];

void mkCrcTab( )
{
unsigned int i, j, c;

    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    {
    c = i;
    for( j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
        if( c&1 )
        c = (c>>1) ^ CRCPOLY;
        else
        c = (c>>1);
    CRC_TABLE[i] = c;
    crcinvtab[c>>24] = (c<<8) ^ i;
    }
}

void CryptoSetPassword(const uint8_t *data, uint32_t size) {
    uint32_t key0 = 0x12345678;
    uint32_t key1 = 0x23456789;
    uint32_t key2 = 0x34567890;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        UPDATE_KEYS(data[i]);

    KeyMem0 = key0;
    KeyMem1 = key1;
    KeyMem2 = key2;
    printf("%zu\n",key0);
    printf("%zu\n",key1);
    printf("%zu\n",key2);
}

void RestoreKeys()
  {
    Key0 = KeyMem0;
    Key1 = KeyMem1;
    Key2 = KeyMem2;
}

uint32_t decrypt(uint8_t *data, uint32_t size, uint8_t *dec) {
    uint32_t key0 = Key0;
    uint32_t key1 = Key1;
    uint32_t key2 = Key2;
    
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        DECRYPT_BYTE_1
        uint8_t b = (uint8_t)(data[i] ^ DECRYPT_BYTE_2);
        UPDATE_KEYS(b);
        dec[i] = b;
    }
  
    Key0 = key0;
    Key1 = key1;
    Key2 = key2;
  
    return size;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t pasw[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    uint8_t cipher[12] = {0x8B, 0x1E, 0xEE, 0x63, 0x9E, 0xDA, 0x90, 0x3E, 0x7A, 0x90, 0x14, 0xCB};
    uint8_t plain[12] = {0x9C, 0x9A, 0xC7, 0x0E, 0xF3, 0x5A, 0x15, 0x85, 0xC7, 0x5C, 0xE9, 0x7F};
    uint8_t deci[12] = {};
    uint64_t t0 = get_time();
    mkCrcTab();
    CryptoSetPassword(pasw, sizeof(pasw));
    uint32_t out = decrypt(cipher, sizeof(cipher),deci);

    if (memcmp(deci, plain, sizeof(plain)) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", "Decryption successful");
    } else {
        printf("Decryption failed. Decrypted data:\n");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(deci); i++) {
            printf("%02X ", deci[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    uint64_t t1 = get_time();
    printf("\ntime = %lu ms\n", t1 - t0);

    return 0;
}

The code prints out keys and if i use those keys to save the deciphered file using bkcrack, the output isn't the actual valid deflate stream according to infgen.
I have reached a point where i do not understand,
first is this encrypted zip (password 12345678):
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`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`

And then same compression parameters to same file but unencrypted:
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

But i can't decrypt the first stream to the later, even with the correct password, what am i doing wrong?
